# If $G$ is a non-cyclic group of order $n^2$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_n} \oplus \mathbb{Z_n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've independently come up with a question (I know it's been asked before, but I can't find the question online) involving the external direct product, non-cyclic groups and isomorphisms.  So, is the following statement true?

Claim:  "If $G$ is a non-cyclic group of order $n^2$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_n} \oplus \mathbb{Z_n}$."
Where $\mathbb{Z_n} \oplus \mathbb{Z_n}$ is the external direct product of $\mathbb{Z_n}$ and $\mathbb{Z_n}$.

I've been thinking about this for a few hours, but really can't figure out a good place to start (or a counter-example).

Comment: In any event, if $n=6$, then $S_3$ is a non-cyclic group of order six...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$ is abelian, while there are many non-cyclic groups that are non-abelian (take $S_3$ for example), so the answer to your question as written is immediately no.

However, what if we only consider abelian non-cyclic groups? <s>Then $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ are two counterexamples you might consider.</s> [After OP's edit: a counterexample is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$, which has order $16$ but is not $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$.]

[Note: this is a relevant result that you might already know: if $m$ and $n$ are coprime, then $\mathbb{Z}_m \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$.]

What you might *then* ask is if every abelian group can be written as the direct product of cyclic groups, and this is true, but not obvious: [Classification of finitely generated abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Classification).

Comment: so can a cyclic group be isomorphic to a non-cyclic group?  each with the same order?

Comment: @P.V. No: a cyclic group has an element $g$ of order $n$ that generates the entire group (i.e., the group is $\{1,g,g^2,\ldots, g^{n-1}\}$) while a non-cyclic group cannot have such an element. (This is assuming that you know that [the order of group elements is preserved by isomorphisms](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/group-isomorphisms-preserve-the-order-of-an-element/).)

Answer (score 1):

Asking what every non-cyclic group of a given order looks like is just as hard as asking what every group of a given order looks like. This is a very hard problem. For example see [this article](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2946623?uid=3739728&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21104012952771).

Now if you wanted to know what every *abelian* group of a given order looks like that is [possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group).

Answer (score 1):

The question should be formulated as follows.

- Let $p$ be a prime.  Consider an abelian group $A$ of order $p^2.$  Prove that either $A$ is cyclic or $A={\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}\oplus {\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}.$
- Let $n$ have three or more divisors (i.e. either there are two different primes dividing $n$, or there is one prime $p$ such that $p^2|n$).  Then there are more than two abelian groups of order $n^2$, up to isomorphism, that are non cyclic.

I would suggest the following to start with: think of Lagrange's theorem (for the first part).

Answer (score -1):

The non cyclic-group $G=Z_2\times Z_2$ is of order $4$, but is not isomorphic to $Z_4\oplus Z_4$.

Comment: This is not a counterexample --- it is isomorphic to $Z_2 \oplus Z_2$ as the question would indicate.

Comment: There is an edit on the original text!